# Outlook 2010: Can I search Only My: Inbox, All Inbox Subfolders, and Specified Archive File Folders all at once

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

The setup is a user that has a laptop with Outlook 2010.  We have Outlook hosted by Sherweb.  The user that has a large number of emails (40,000) in a single Inbox subfolder.  (I believe) Having such a large number of emails in an inox is slowing the users laptop down and I want to start moving old emails to a seperate pst file on a machine on our network.

The problem I have is the user needs to be able to search all 40,000 emails.  Right now he can can search do a search on the single subfolder.  I would like to be able to move some of the emails to a seperate pst so I can compact the Inbox and still give them a 'one-click' search function that is still fairly quick.

I don't think the 'Search All Outlook Items' is the soltuion because this will search all outlook folders -- sent items, other public folders.

P.S. I'm not a expericenced outlook administrator, so there may be some assumptions in my questions that are wrong.  I have no problem with somebody showing the error of my ways.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that, generally, it isn't a good idea to leave a lot of mail in the inbox - though you should also clear out the "Sent Items" folder regularly as well, this can also slow things down.

As for searching, you can of course create a Search Folder that incorporates specific folders. However, this is a fixed search so not really what you want.

Advanced Find also allows you to select the folders to search but, again, this is not what you are asking for.

Indeed, I can't think of any way to achieve what you want specifically.

By the way though, if the users PC is of a reasonably good specification, and running Windows 7, Windows Indexing is really very good. I currently have over 380,000 items in my index.

Finally, you can exclude public folders fairly easily from searches. Click on the "Search Tools" that appears when you click in the search box.